# B&N Audiobooks on Novel

Tags: pandigital-novel, audiobooks

My wife has a Pandigital Novel and would like to be able to listen to audiobooks from Barnes & Noble.  The people at the Barnes & Noble store said this can only be done on a Nook.  However, since we just recently (last Fall) bought the Novel, I'm not much inclined to turn around and buy another tablet/e-reader for her if it can be avoided.

Is there any way the Novel can download/play Barnes & Noble's audiobooks?

Answer (score 3):

After some googling, it appears that B&N audiobooks are in MP3 format with no DRM.  That means they should play on **almost everything** that can play audio, including the Novel.

**Edit:** Their [FAQ](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/help/cds2.asp?PID=27154&cds2Pid=8510&linkid=1636468) says exactly that, and mentions how to download the files.

Comment: @MatthewReed - Thanks for the research.  I'll take a closer look into it the next chance I get, but apparently downloading/playing B&N's audiobooks still isn't as straightforward as that - do you have any insights as to what my wife might be doing wrong?

Comment: B&N's FAQ is pretty good and actually says audiobooks can be put on many devices http://www.barnesandnoble.com/help/cds2.asp?PID=27154&cds2Pid=8510&linkid=1636468

Answer (score 0):

I have a Pandigital and DO play mp3 audiobooks on it without any issue. However, I have been borrowing them from the public library and it seems you have to got through iTunes to drag and drop them to you PDN.